# How to change position of pagination in ag-grid

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and when I get my grid the pagination is automatically on the left side,
How can I change position to the right side
[image]

Comment: In the [demos](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-pagination/), the pagination is already to the right. Why is yours on the left? Is RTL enabled? Regardless, the answer is to move them with CSS. Inspect the element with a class of `ag-paging-panel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the paging-panel CSS. The element has a class named `.ag-paging-panel`

Give a parent element this CSS rule

```css
.my-parent .ag-paging-panel {
  justify-content: flex-end
}
```